# IP address and Socket.h on Windows in C language

Tags: c, cross-platform, winsock

In this code, the purpose is to display the IP address in simple manner.

```
/* Simple IP getter, working on Linux. */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h> // for strncpy  

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int
main()
{
    int fd;
    struct ifreq ifr;

    fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

    // I want to get an IPv4 IP address  
    ifr.ifr_addr.sa_family = AF_INET;

    // I want IP address attached to "eth0"  
    strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, "eth0", IFNAMSIZ-1);

    ioctl(fd, SIOCGIFADDR, &ifr);

    close(fd);

    // display result  
    printf("%s\n", inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *)&ifr.ifr_addr)->sin_addr));

    return 0;
}
```

It works on Linux, but if you try to compile it with mingw32 on windows, 
even with -lw32_.. it does not work.

I have tried to find winsock.dll and add it into the directory but it does not help.

Any ideas would be helpful. thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Linux; however, in windows, you need to use winsock library. The following link gives more info about winsock. 
[Getting Started with Winsock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) I've implemented my own class based on it.

Answer (score 0):

MinGW32 isn't a multi-platform compiler. It is a Windows compiler.
Because Windows has different functions for socket handling, you can't use the Linux code for Windows.

You could use `#ifdef`s to handle the problem platform dependent codes, but I don't think you want to do that. I suggest you to use Cygwin. It's exactly for this purpose: compile Linux code for Windows without much changes.

There is a nice description for Netbeans how to configure it to compile with Cygwin.

Answer (score 0):

Here is winsock client code example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737591(v=vs.85).aspx, and here is the server code:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737593(v=vs.85).aspx. And use **Microsoft visual studio express**.